# How to trim spaces from System.out.printf Java

Tags: java, trim

Could you please get an advice, how to trim space from System.out.printf in Java:

```
public class Part3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N = 10;
        int ct=0,n=0,i=1,j=1;
        while(n<N)
        {
            j=1;
            ct=0;
            while(j<=i)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                    ct++;
                j++;
            }
            if(ct==2)
            {
                System.out.printf("%d%s", i);
                n++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Current result is with last space: `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29`

Expected result is without last space: `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29`

Best regards

Comment: Why `"%d%s"` since you don't supply an argument. This code throws a `java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the 'add separator before all but the first' approach.

In outline, and not really attempting to map this to your specific case, it goes like this:

```
  String sep = "";
  for (*some loop or other*) {
       System.out.printf("%s%d", sep, nextNum);
       sep = " ";
  }
```

I find this more compact than writing conditionals for determining whether this is the first (or last) element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `%s` from the printf and perform a check after each number to test if you are on your last iteration of your loop. If you aren't on the last iteration, print a space.

```
if(ct==2)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d%s", i);
        n++;
        if (n != N) 
             {
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach following condition inside `if(ct==2) {` :

```
if(n==N-1)
    System.out.print(i);
else
    System.out.printf("%d ", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

When printing separated output, e.g. space-separated like here, it is not always easy to determine when the *last* value is printed. Here it is, because you're printing exactly 10 values, but what if the code was to print prime numbers less than 120? At the time we print the last prime number (113), we don't know if there are more.

Therefore, it is much easier to print the separator *before* the value, and suppress the *first* separator:

```java
boolean first = true;

while (...) { // some loop here
    // some logic here
    if (...) { // decide if we need to print

        // print values separated by spaces
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            System.out.print(' '); // print separator
        }
        System.out.print(value);

    }
}
```

Instead of using a `boolean`, you can use a `String` variable to carry the separator, and initially make it an empty string. The code is more concise, but it's a matter of opinion whether it's a better solution:

```java
String sep = ""; // no separator before first value

while (...) { // some loop here
    // some logic here
    if (...) { // decide if we need to print

        // print values separated by spaces
        System.out.print(sep + value);
        sep = " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: My, but your edit to suggest using a string separator looks …. familiar.

Comment: @user14644949 It does. I did actually edit the answer and add that before I saw your answer, since I've used that technique multiple times myself. Since I obviously like your answer, I did up-vote it, even though it uses the much slower `printf()`. 